# How to do a fast numerical computation of an oscillatory integral including HeunC function using Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions

I am trying to numerically compute the following integral in Mathematica

```
NIntegrate[(x + 2)*Exp[2*I*a*(x + 2)]*
  HeunC[-4*I*b, -4*I*b, 1 + 4*I*b, 1, -4*I*b, -x/2], {x, 1, 1000}]
```

where HeunC is the confluent Heun function. Mathematica can numerically compute this integral for the known values of a and b. There are two problems here: When I increase the value of a and b, the integral becomes highly oscillatory and it takes a long time to be computed. Also, even for the small value of a and b, Mathematica spends a long time to compute this integral when the upper bound is 1000, but it is pretty fast when I decrease the upper bound. As an example, we can choose $a=5$ and $b=0.1$, and when I run the program, it takes longer than 5 minutes to compute the integral. Could you please help me with this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Can you, please, provide additional details of what values of a, b give what timings for you? And please also clarify what the other values you would like to use are? This will improve the answers you get & the experience of future users at the same time. Thanks!

Comment: $a$ and be $b$ are real and positive. I should compute this integral for $0<a,b<\infty$.  When I choose $a=5$ and $b=0.1$, it takes longer than 5 minutes to compute the integral.

Comment: Shohreh, can you update your question with such information? This will make it easier for potential answerers to see the relevant information.